# Good reference for makefile syntax (with examples)?

Tags: makefile, android-ndk

I am developing native libs for android via its NDK - makefile syntax is proving a problem.

Can anyone point me toward a good, allround reference for makefile syntax (prefereabilly with examples for Android).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here: http://www.gnu.org/s/make/manual/